# difference between structure pointers

Tags: c++, c

```
struct node
{
 int data;
 struct node *next;
};
```

What is difference between following two functions:

```
void traverse(struct node *q)
{ }
```

and

```
void traverse(struct node **q)
{ }
```

How can i call above functions from main program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first argument list passes a pointer to a `struct node`. This allows you to change the `struct node` in the body of the function. For instance:

```
// this will change the structure, caller will see the changes:
q->data = newValue;

// but this will only change q in the function, caller WON'T see the NULL:
q = NULL;
```

The second argument list passes a *pointer to a pointer* to a `struct node`. This allows you to not only change the `struct node` in the body of the function, but also to change what the pointer *points to*. For instance:

```
// this will change the structure, caller will see the changes:
(*q)->data = newValue;

// This will change the pointer, caller will now see a NULL:
*q = NULL:
```

As for calling the two versions of the function, from `main` or otherwise: given a pointer to your structure: `struct node *arg;`,

- you could call the first version like this: `traverse(arg);`
- and the second version like this: `traverse(&arg);`

Alternately, given a structure declared as `struct node arg;`, you can make a pointer to it:

```
struct node arg;
struct node *ptrToArg = &arg;
```

And then:

- you could call the first version like this: `traverse(&arg);`
- and the second version like this: `traverse(&ptrToArg);`

Answer (score 4):

```
void traverse(struct node *q)
{ }
```

Takes a pointer to a struct. You would could call it like this:

```
struct node A;
traverse(&A);
```

This function

```
void traverse(struct node **q)
{ }
```

Takes a pointer to a pointer to a struct. You could call it like this:

```
struct node A;
struct node* Aptr = &A;
traverse(&Aptr);
```

Passing a pointers is useful if you want to modify the original variable that you pass to the function, for example, if you had a function like this:

```
void setToNull(struct node ** q){
   *q = NULL;
}
```

Then you could do this:

```
struct node A;
struct node* Aptr = &A;
setToNull(&Aptr);
// Aptr is now equal to NULL.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 void traverse(struct node *q)
```

Simply passes a pointer to the function.

```
 void traverse(struct node **q)
```

Passes a pointer to a pointer, so you can change the original one. It's the C-equivalent of C++'s passing a pointer by reference. In C++, you can just do:

```
 void traverse(node *& q)
```

You'd call them as:

```
 struct node* q;

 //...
 traverse(q); //calls first version
 traverse(&q);//calls second version
```